# How do Instance Methods work in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, rest, mongoose, callback

I'm working on a course in building a REST API with Mongoose. We have a question and an answer document and they're showing how to update the answers to the questions collection using an Instance Method on the Answers Schema. I'm not able to follow along at this point because, i can't tell what the callbacks being passed in as arguments are for and what they're exactly doing to the schema.

```
AnswerSchema.method("update", function(updates, callback) { 

      object.assign(this, updates, {updatedAt: newDate()}); 
      this.parent().save(callback);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose allows you to work with either callbacks or Promises, so you must choose one for your query to get invoked.

If you specify a callback - the query will be executed immediately and the callback will be invoked with the result right after it's done.

If you use Promises, then you need to explicitly call `.then()` at the end of your query to invoke it.

Otherwise, if you don't care about the result you can call `.exec()` which also returns a promise, but does not require handling.